# Why is it not possible to "SELECT" Data as parameters for certain clauses like LIMIT?

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.2

EXAMPLE:

```
CREATE TABLE t (A INT);
INSERT INTO t VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5);
```

This works:

```
SELECT A FROM t WHERE A=(SELECT 1)
```

This does not:

```
SELECT A FROM t LIMIT (SELECT 1);
```

This works:

```
SELECT A FROM t WHERE A=substring((SELECT 123),1,1);
```

This does not:

```
SELECT A FROM t WHERE A=1 PROCEDURE ANALYSE((SELECT 1),10000);
```

What makes some clauses and functions support SELECT statements and others not support it. I would think that running `(SELECT 1)` returns a `1` as a parameter and as long as the parameter is the expected type it should work. This seems to be true in some cases, but not others. Why is that?

Comment: Suppose someone from the original MySQL architecture team comes here and explains at length why they chose to implement it this way; what will it change?

Answer (score 0):

this is the way LIMIT can be done in [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) using variable parameters:

```
SET @skip=1; SET @numrows=5;
PREPARE STMT FROM 'SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT ?, ?';
EXECUTE STMT USING @skip, @numrows;
```

In the place where it says `SET @skip=1`, One can also write `SET @skip=(SELECT 1)`.